# Add Class to Specific Paragraph of the_content()

Tags: filters, the-content

Let's say I want to give the first paragraph bold text by adding a body class to the first paragraph.  Is there a way to filter the output of

```
the_content();
```

or any other paragraph? First paragraph? Last paragraph?

I know I can do this using Javascript or CSS (:firstchild), but is there a native WordPress way?

Thanks.

J

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following bit of code adds a class to the first paragraph output by `the_content`:

```
function first_paragraph($content){
    return preg_replace('/<p([^>]+)?>/', '<p$1 class="intro">', $content, 1);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'first_paragraph');
```

Add the above to your theme's functions.php file.

Then in your CSS add something like:

```
p.intro { font-weight:bold; }
```

I can't claim credit for this solution (see [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/automatically-bold-first-paragraph-of-content) in the WP forums) but I tested it and it worked great for me in WordPress 3.3.2. You should be able to modify it as needed to target whichever paragraph your heart desires.

Comment: There is an issue with this: If there is already a class assigned, you will end up with two class attributes.

Comment: @m0r7if3r Plus: It won't work for anything than the 1st paragraph

Comment: @m0r7if3r, can you help me understand when that would be an issue?

Comment: @Ryan Absolutely. If the first `<p>` of `the_content` looks like `<p class="any_class more_classes">`, it will be automatically replaced with `<p class="intro">` rather than becoming something like `<p class="any_class more_classes intro'>`. As I consider it now, I believe it might be possible to design a regex that would do the classname extraction for you...

Comment: @Ryan Absolutely, Thanks! It worked. This option enables us to call a specific part of the_content(), right? Do you know how to call the first paragraph into a the_content() function?

Comment: @m0r7if3r I realized that, but it led me to wonder why one would have classes on the paragraphs to begin with, vs. targeting them with a more general CSS declaration. I can see having classes on a paragraph via jQuery, but I think the OP implied that jQuery was not being used here. I was just curious.

Comment: @PolvanRijn I could be having a daft moment, but yes, the answer I left above lets you target the first paragraph of `the_content()`.