# add class to term_description

Tags: filters

trying to filter the output of term_description to include a class https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description

```
function add_class_to_term_description() { ?>

<?php  echo '<div class="cell">' . term_description() . '</div>'; ?>

<?php  }
add_filter( 'term_description', 'add_class_to_term_description' ); ?>
```

im getting and empty cell class returned hundreds of times which is exhausting the memory. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this hook `term_description` exists? I just couldn't find it online.. If it does, to proper way to apply a filter to it is `return` instead of `echo`, but you're missing what to filter as the function's first param. `add_class_to_term_description( $term_description ) { return '<div class="cell">' . $term_description . '</div>'; }` THAT if the hook exists.

Comment: thanks. its working to some extent. It returns `<div class="term-description"><div class="cell"><p>content</p></div></div>` so im thinking i need to use a filter to remove the container div. something like `remove_filter($term_desciption, 'the_wrapper_div');
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does the trick

```
<?php function add_class_to_term_description($term_description) {
  echo '<div class="cell">' . $term_description. '</div>';
}
add_filter( 'term_description', 'add_class_to_term_description' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is on the right track, using the value that is passed into the function. However, you should not be echoing anything because this is a filter. You should instead return the value.

```
<?php
function add_class_to_term_description( $term_description ) {
  return '<div class="cell">' . $term_description. '</div>';
}
add_filter( 'term_description', 'add_class_to_term_description' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use passed `$value` instead of `term_description()` function:

```
function add_class_to_term_description() {
  echo '<div class="cell">' . $value . '</div>';
}
add_filter( 'term_description', 'add_class_to_term_description' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested many potential solutions, including all the answers above. They either did not work or did not work as expected - some output empty paragraphs, other do nothing. The best solution for me was to use the PHP function [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to perform a search for the opening paragraph HTML tag and to insert the class attribute with the value I need like this:

```
function add_class_to_term_descr($content){
    return preg_replace('/<p([^>]+)?>/', '<p$1 class="lead">', $content, 1);
}
add_filter('term_description', 'add_class_to_term_descr');
```

This solution can be easily modified to match other types of WordPress output, like "div" tag for example. I based my solution on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51682/188573) and modified it according to my needs.